# Swiftmailer setFrom address doesn't change anything

Tags: php, swiftmailer

I know my question seems strange. I am using PHP and SwiftMailer package. Here is my code:

```
$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.gmail.com', 465, "ssl")
    ->setUsername('adresim@gmail.com')
    ->setPassword('my_pass');
$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance($title)
    ->setFrom(array('adresim@hotmail.com'))
    ->setTo($to_adresses)
    ->setReplyTo("another_address")
    ->setBody($body, "text/html");
```

here is the problem. When i send a mail it appears that it came from my gmail address. In this example i am using gmail smtp and everything is fine but setFrom command doesn't seem to do anything at all. Even if i set the from address as a Hotmail address, my mail goes fine and it is sent from my gmail adres. What does setFrom command do? How can i make the mail be sent from the given FROM adres? If smtp connection username the is the only important thing, why there is a setFrom command?

Comment: 1./ FROM is not set because gmail overrides that parameter with account email that you use. 2./ This is the correct way to send email. Why would FROM be different?

Comment: i tried to connect to smtp with another address and send the mail from another gmail adres so it can be actually sent from the "from adres" but i realized it doesn't make sense. so setFrom also doesn't make sense. thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gmail requires you to validate From addresses before sending mail as that email address. So you need to add a new sender in your personal gmail account and validate it.

Answer taken from:

[When using Gmail for SMTP, can you set a different "from" address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431631/using-gmail-for-smtp-setfrom)