# smtp email from name not working

Tags: c#, email, web-config

I have a contact us page set up on my website and I would like to make it appear like it is coming from a different email address.

```
<mailSettings>
  <smtp from="info@magazine.com">
    <network host="smtp.gmail.com" enableSsl="true" port="587" userName="admin@magazine.com" password="password" defaultCredentials="false" />
  </smtp>
</mailSettings>
```

So I make my mail client and try and send the email

```
 MailMessage message = new MailMessage();

 message.To.Add(new MailAddress(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ContactEmailTo"]));

 message.Subject = "Contact Request";
 message.Body = body;

 SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
 client.Send(message);
```

However, when I receive the email, I receive it from the admin address.

Comment: It is most likely gmail preventing you from using an alias. I am not familiar with gmail, but does it offer you an option to create an alias with the alternate email address? Otherwise, can you create a gmail account with the email address you are sending from and connect to that instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use one of the constructor overloads on `MailAddress` to specify an address and display name like so:

```
MailAddress address = new MailAddress("user@website.com", "John Smith");
```

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1s17zfkf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx for more info.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're sending through GMail. Their SMTP server rewrites the FROM address. See for example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1332510/how-to-change-from-address-when-using-gmail-smtp-server).

If you want to use GMail, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431631/when-using-gmail-for-smtp-can-you-set-a-different-from-address?lq=1) suggests adding the FROM email in your account settings under:

> Settings -> Accounts -> Send mail as -> Add another email address you own

The other option is to use a different SMTP server that allows you to set your FROM address.