# Trigger Email from Firestore extension in firebase isn't picking the 'from' address from email doc

Tags: firebase, firebase-extensions

As per documentation, if I post a doc in firestore collection with 'from' email id then the email received via this extension should have that from address but it's always 'username@gmail.com' from smtp url(smtps://username@gmail.com@smtp.gmail.com:465) which I provided during extension set up. Has anyone faced this issue?

I don't want this address which I provided during the extension set up which is like organization email which doesn't make any sense for the end user.

username@gmail.com is my personal email and then I created a app password in my google account and provided it in smtp password field.

My extension settings:

[image: Ext Configuration]

Comment: Can you share the settings/configuration of your extension?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec OP added the config. 

Comment: @anirudh See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431631/when-using-gmail-for-smtp-can-you-set-a-different-from-address and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1332510/how-to-change-from-address-when-using-gmail-smtp-server

Comment: Thanks. So I can't change from email so easily. Now I will explain my requirement here, I am trying to create a SaaS kind of product, and Firebase Firestore is the DB here. What I was trying to achieve was that different clients of my products would send emails using this extension to their teams/customers etc. via creating docs in a collection so 'from' address has to be theirs(different clients of my product). But looking at the above options of changing 'from' address won't work in my case. Any suggestion from Firebase team to achieve in terms of another ext or something else? Thanks.

Comment: You could use a service like https://sendgrid.com/. HOWEVER be aware that such service will only authorize the creation of from addresses that are verified. In other words letting your end-users creating any from address will not be possible, to avoid phishing or similar actions.