# from_email is not working in django EmailMessage and using EMAIL_HOST_USER instead

Tags: django, email, sendmessage, django-email

I am trying to use django's builtin Email class `EmailMessage` to send an email with attachment like below

```
def send_email(path, from_email, to_list, file_name):
    subject = 'Output for csv file %s'%(file_name,)
    body = 'Please find the attached output file your csv input file %s'%(file_name,)
    message = EmailMessage(subject, body, from_email, to_list)
    message.attach_file(path)
    message.send()

send_email('/home/user/hello.csv', 'myself@gmail.com', ['client@gmail.com'], 'functional_test')
```

And my Email settings in `settings.py` are

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'actual@myhost.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'password'
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
```

So from the above settings the EMAIL_HOST_USER was `actual@myhost.com` and when i am calling my `send_email` function i am specifying `from_email` as `myself@gmail.com`.

So when i received the email i am receiving it from `actual@myhost.com` instead of  `myself@gmail.com` even though we specified different `from_email`.

Is there anything that i can do to receive the mails with from address as  `myself@gmail.com` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The email\_from in Django send\_mail function not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6803009/the-email-from-in-django-send-mail-function-not-working)

Answer (score 1):

Got the same issue, @HaydenCrocker is right.

It’s Gmail’s restrictionists, need to change another email server if really want to customers from_email.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Gmail, you need to add the email you want use as alias

Follow instructions below

https://support.google.com/a/answer/33327?product_name=UnuFlow&hl=en&visit_id=638041629555716720-783343126&rd=1&src=supportwidget0&hl=en

Answer (score -2):

You have to add `DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL`, see [the documentation.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#default-from-email)