# default :from is not working when using gmail SMTP

Tags: ruby-on-rails, smtp, gmail

In my rails application, I am using gmail SMTP settings.But even though I gave this `ActionMailer::Base.default :from => 'some@emailaddress.com'` in my environments file , The from address which showing in the email is the user_name field which I gave in the SMTP settings along with the password.

Is there any way to display any custom email address?

Pls comment If u didn't get my question

Comment: what happens when you hit the reply button? Does it at least send to the right address?

Comment: I've given default :reply_to => "some@add.ress". And it is working when i hit reply button.But I want to display any custom email address in the header..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1332510/how-to-change-from-address-when-using-gmail-smtp-server << This link is saying like we can't. Somebody please confirm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either send from the gmail account you really want to be the sender, use a non-gmail SMTP server (that allows setting other senders), or use Amazon SES.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting :sender instead of :from.