# Codeigniter email always sends from 'my@gmail.com' instead of the input email given

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, smtp, gmail

Today I made a contact form on my website. All is working fine, the emails are sending correctly to the specified email (`$this->email->to('myemail@address.com')`).

In my application/config/email.com I have:

```
$config = Array(
    'protocol' => 'smtp',
    'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
    'smtp_port' => 465,
    'smtp_user' => 'myemail@gmail.com',
    'smtp_pass' => 'mypassword',
    'mailtype'  => 'html', 
    'charset'   => 'iso-8859-1'
);
```

But now every mail I send from my website are recieved as 'myemail@gmail.com' when I look into the mailbox of myemail@address.com.

I don't know if this is the standard behaviour?

How can I use the email typed in into the input box as the 'from' email?

My controller function looks like this:

```
    public function sendmail()
    {
        $config['mailtype'] = 'html';
        $config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
        $config['smtp_host'] = 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com';
        $config['smtp_port'] = 465;
        $config['smtp_user'] = 'user@gmail.com';
        $config['smtp_pass'] = 'user@owrb';
        $confog['wordwrap'] = TRUE;

        $this->load->library('email', $config);
        $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");

        $this->email->from($this->input->post('from'), $this->input->post('name'));

        $this->email->to('info@keessonnema.nl');    

        $this->email->subject($this->input->post('subject'));      

        $naam = $this->input->post('name');
        $email = $this->input->post('from');
        $tel = $this->input->post('tel');
        $site = $this->input->post('site');
        $sub = $this->input->post('subject');
        $msg = $this->input->post('message');

        $this->email->message("
        <div id='email'>
        <p><b>Bedrijf:</b> <br/> $naam</p>
        <p><b>Email:</b> <br/> $email</p>
        <p><b>Tel:</b> <br/> $tel</p>
        <p><b>Website:</b> <br/> $site</p>
        <p><b>Onderwerp:</b> <br/> $sub</p>
        <p><b>Toelichting:</b> <br/> $msg</p>
        </div>
        ");

        $success = ('
        <div style="position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);">Uw Email is succesvol verzonden!</div>
        ');

        if($this->email->send())
        {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', 'Email successvol verzonden.');
            redirect('contact/index');
        }
        else
        {
            show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
        }
    }
```

Hope someone can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that Gmail restricts any arbitrary "from" address.
Why ? To prevent spoofing.

(Imagine if it were possible, you could send anyone an email from "big_bank@blabla.com"...)

**EDIT :** A quick google search yielded this : [How to change from-address when using gmail smtp server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1332510/how-to-change-from-address-when-using-gmail-smtp-server)

> Google rewrites the From and Reply-To headers in messages you send via
>   it's SMTP service to values which relate to your gmail account.
>
> The SMTP feature of gmail isn't intended to be an open or relay
>   service. If it allowed any values for the From header, it would
>   significantly dilute Google's standing with spam services, as there
>   would be no way to verify the credentials of the sender.

**Source :** https://stackoverflow.com/a/1332803/2615399

***Tl;dr :*** you can't (...using gmail).

Comment: So I will have to change my smtp to sendmail for example. Will look at this tommorrow. Thanks a lot