# Rails 4 + ActionMailer: ":from" is filled with incorrect email address

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, actionmailer

I am fighting with setting up the "from" information that is shown in the email in header.

It still shows incorrect email address.
In the mailer class, I manually set the default email address:

```
class NotificationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default content_type: "text/html", :from => 'default@email.com'
```

I also specified this in the method for sending the email(s):

```
  def welcome_email(user)
    @user = user
    mail(to: @user.email, subject: "Welcome!", from: 'default@email.com')    
  end
```

But when I receive this email, it's from `my-personal-email@gmail.com`. I searched through the Rails app where is this email address set up and it's here:

`config/initializers/setup_email.rb`:

```
ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :address => "smtp.gmail.com",
  :port => 587,
  :domain => "logistadvise.com",
  :user_name => "my-personal-email@gmail.com",
  :password => "mypassword",
  :authentication => "plain",
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

Emails are sent out well, but worries me that I am unable to properly set the "from" header.

How to do that?

Thank you.

Comment: It looks like Rails is probably doing the right thing, but gmail seems to only allow the 'from' address to be that of the account holder. See this question/answer for details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1332510/how-to-change-from-address-when-using-gmail-smtp-server

Comment: Kind of "yeah"; when I check the logs, I see that the email was sent out from the proper email address (`default@email.com`), but in Gmail I see the personal one.

Comment: I have a similar but different problem. 'to' address is filled with 'from' address when I call `deliver_now`, but when I check mailer object itself, like `mailer.to`, it shows correct 'to' address. What could be the culprit?

Comment: Okay I figured out. There was a mail interceptor that modifies `to` address when running in development environment.