# From: address not working on PHP mail() with sSMTP

Tags: php, email, ubuntu, ssmtp

I have PHP 5.5.9 on Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS. 
I use sSMTP and Google's SMTP to send mails on PHP's mail() function. Something has changed, because now when I recieve the email from server, sender is www-data, even tho I have specified headers for email as shown below

```
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "From: Site Webmaster <noreply@myserver.com> \r\n";
$headers .= "To: ".$email."\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/alternative;boundary=" . $boundary . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail('', $subject, $message, $headers) or die(var_dump(error_get_last()));
```

It works otherwise, but as I sad, sender is shown as www-data

---

I'v tried to add lines to revaliases on sSMTP, and I have

```
FromLineOverride=YES
```

in ssmtp.conf, but it still doesn't work

Comment: I don't think you're using SMTP.  That looks like the typical PHP mail.

Comment: Try adding an alias www-data noreply@myserver.co

Comment: Recommend changeing to Phpmailer.  For full control

Comment: I'm skeptical that you're successfully using GMail for your SMTP server (unless theres a different Google SMTP service?) because GMail will [_always_ rewrite your email's `FROM:` header](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1332510/how-to-change-from-address-when-using-gmail-smtp-server) to the user that authenticated with GMail. This is supposed to prevent spamming.

Comment: So you suggest, that Gmail is the reason the From: address is not working? Since mail goes trough, but sender changes to www-data

Comment: Also, aliases won't work. "newaliases: Aliases are not used in sSMTP". 
And the PhpMailer won't fix the problem. I still need to use remote SMTP-server for the mail to be sent.