# Mail getting sent from a different email address

Tags: php, email, smtp, gmail

I am facing this problem where the mail is getting sent as a different email rather than the one specified.

```
                    $from_name = 'send';
                    $from = 'send@test.com';
                    $to = 'receive@test.com';
                    $to_name = 'receive';
                    $also_to = 'cc@test.com';
                    $also_to_name = 'cc';
                    $message = 'Dear receive Thank you for the booking';
                    $message .= '<br><br>'.$homepage;
                    $mail = new PHPMailer();
                    $mail->SMTPDebug  = 0;
                    $mail->IsSMTP();    
                    $mail->Port = 465;
                    $mail->Host = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com";
                    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
                    $mail->Username = 'send1@test.com';
                    $mail->Password = ******;

                    $mail->SetFrom($from,$from_name );
                    $mail->AddReplyTo($from,$from_name );
                    $mail->Subject  = 'Booking Details';
                    $mail->MsgHTML($message);
                    $mail->AddAddress($to,$to_name);
                    $mail->AddCC($also_to,$also_to_name);
```

When I sent it using this code the mail goes with name as 'send' but not the 'send@test.com' email address it gets sent from "send -> send1@test.com" rather than send -> send@test.com.
Above I have mentioned the smtp details that i have used. Also when i change:

```
                    $mail->Username = 'send@test.com';
                    $mail->Password = ******;
```

The mail does not go through to any email address. I hope this is clear enough for you guys and I would appreciate any help. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

`$mail->Username = send1@test.com;`

this need to be in quotes like :

`$mail->Username = "send1@test.com"`;

Check whether this resolves you issue ?

If not try setting debug to true `$mail->SMTPDebug  = 1;`

and see what's being actually sent to gmail server

By default gmail will use the account's email address

Ref : [How to change from-address when using gmail smtp server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1332510/how-to-change-from-address-when-using-gmail-smtp-server)

Comment: sorry about that, but the mails still don't go if i add the quotes

Comment: could you please paste the received raw email headers ?

Comment: send <send1@test.com> where send is the name given and send1@test.com is the incorrect email address it should be send@test.com

Answer (score 0):

Look at this: http://phpmailer.worxware.com/index.php?pg=properties

> $From     public  root@localhost  Sets the From email address for the message

and

> $FromName     public  Root User   Sets the From name of the message

So you want specifically add the following:

```
$mail->From = $from;
$mail->FromName= $from_name;
```

Comment: so changing this in the class.phpmailer.php to the above will rectify it? that would mean i have to include the filename in phpmailer file too right? What if i change those values in the php mailer to the name and id i require?

Comment: I don't know the name of the script that you show above. Just add those two lines in the same place you add the rest of the parameters and give it a try.

Comment: OK I will try that. What about the $mail->SetFrom() function? is that still required or do i include those values inside the $mail->SetFrom function?

Comment: I tried that the from is still showing the same email id in smtp username

Answer (score -1):

You have to call `setFrom` method to set the sender's mail address and name:

```
$mail->SetFrom('send@test.com', 'Your Name');
```

Comment: $mail->SetFrom($from,$from_name ); I have included that in the above code adding the variables. Giving the actual values will help?