# Using PhpMailer and gmail for contact us form

Tags: php, smtp, gmail, phpmailer

I am working on this [basic website](http://codeevents.hostzi.com) which contains a contact us form. This contact form is supposed to send mail to a predefined mail address with user feedback. As I am using gmail as smtp, this does not let users to send email with other email address and replaces user email address with default user email address. What should I do to use my email address as a contact mail address, while the users mail address as sender mail address?

For example:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer;

//$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               // Enable verbose debug output

$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'sakib.cse11.cuet@gmail.com';                 // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'mypassword';                           // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to

$mail->setFrom('sakibdterror@gmail.com', 'Mailer');
$mail->addAddress('sakib.cse11.cuet@gmail.com', 'Sakib Rahman');     // Add a recipient
               // Name is optional
$mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');
// $mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
// $mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');

// $mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
// $mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name
$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = 'Here adasfffasfs is the subject';
$mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
}
```

[image]

Whatever the from address, the mail is always sent from the username address(For example I have set mail->setForm ='sakibdterro@gmail.com", but google replaces it with the default username "sakib.cse11.cuet@gmail.com")

Comment: Post your (relevant) source code.

Comment: I did @Fred-ii- . Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I have difficulty understanding what you mean by: *"this does not let users to send email with other email address and replaces user email address with default user email address."* - Can you elaborate on that and how it fails?

Comment: Usually, a "From" sender can be taken from the form's email input, if that is what you are asking. Given the (unknown form's input), i.e.: `<input type="text" name="from_email">` you would then use `$from_email = $_POST['from_email'];` then use `$mail->setFrom($from_email, 'Sender mail');` type of thing; again... "if" that is what you are asking.

Comment: No, that is not what I am asking. Please take a look at edited post @Fred-ii-. Whatever I set as from_email address, it is replaced by the default username for smtp.

Comment: OooOOoohhhh  I know what this is about now. You have no control over that. You have an Gmail alias happening here and it's replacing it with your "original" Gmail created account.

Comment: Yes, what should I do? Is there any alternatives?

Comment: I'm afraid not.

Comment: So, how the contact us pages are generally handled? Using other smtp services or any third party services like "MailChimp"?

Comment: You could but then they'll ask you for your email address and it will use that as a default; you would need to use an alternate email address and I am afraid that you will be back to "square one".

Comment: So what is the solution? I mean there's absolutely millions of examples with contact us pages in websites. What do they do?

Comment: If you are asking of how to send an email on behalf of other user, it is not possible by design. What other millions do, is they add sender's email from the form to the email body.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change from-address when using gmail smtp server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1332510/how-to-change-from-address-when-using-gmail-smtp-server)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please search before posting: This has been [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1332510/how-to-change-from-address-when-using-gmail-smtp-server) on here many times before, and [the contact form example provided with PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/contactform.phps) shows you exactly how to do it.

Gmail does not let you set arbitrary from addresses, though you can set up fixed aliases in your gmail settings. The reason it does not allow it is because it's forgery, and will cause your messages to fail SPF checks.

The right way to do this is to put your own address as the from address, and add the submitter's address as a reply-to. This way you're not forging anything, and when you reply to a message, it will go to who you expect:

```
$mail->setFrom('sakib.cse11.cuet@gmail.com');
$mail->addReplyTo($_POST['from_email']);
```

Comment: Correct! Worked like a charm. Thank you in 2019 :)