# Can't change from header on localhost mail PHP

Tags: php, localhost, sendmail

I'm trying to send emails from my localhost, but I'm running across an issue that keeps coming up. I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15965376/how-to-configure-xampp-to-send-mail-from-localhost/18185233#18185233) which explained how to set up XAMPP to send email, and the emails are sent, but when I try changing the `From` header, nothing happens. The email gets sent, but it's sent from my personal email.

I tried removing both the `sendmail_from` in `php.ini` and `force_sender` in `sendmail.ini`, but neither worked. I tried adding the `-f` parameter to the `mail` function, and it didn't work. I've even tried restarting XAMPP several times, but still nothing. Is there something I've overlooked or is there no way to do this?

**PHP**

```
<?php
  $headers = "From: Joe Smith <joe@joesmith.com>" . "\r\n";
  mail("recipient@gmail.com", "This is a test message", "Yup, it's a test message all right.", $headers, "-f joe@joesmith.com");
?>
```

**php.ini**

```
[mail function]
SMTP=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=587
sendmail_from = 
sendmail_path = "\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"
```

**sendmail.ini**

```
[sendmail]

smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=587
error_logfile=error.log
debug_logfile=debug.log
auth_username=mypersonalemail@gmail.com
auth_password=mypersonalpassword
```

Comment: GMail possibly doesn't allow changing the `From` header and replaces it with a different one

Comment: Your sendmail_from  doesn't have anything. Have you tried setting it? Plus, what's the OS? You can also set it in the `sendmail_path` as `sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -F"Full Name" -f'emailaddress@example.com'`.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are using Google's SMTP servers and they don't allow changing the 'From' header.

This was answered here:
[How to change from-address when using gmail smtp server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1332510/how-to-change-from-address-when-using-gmail-smtp-server)

Answer (score 0):

I just did a project similar to this. Depending on your needs, you can use [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) to change your "reply to" address. Although it's not the same as changing the from address, it achieves a similar goal, is easy to use, and has a good community. Also, it works perfectly with Google Mail.