# Laravel send email with a dynamic sender

Tags: laravel, gmail

Hello I have a problem sending email form contact form with a dynamic sender using gmail smtp:

```
public function build()
{
    return $this->from($this->data['email'])
        ->subject( 'Message from  Mr.'. $this->data['full_name'] )
        ->markdown('emails.contact.contact')
        ->with('data', $this->data);
}
```

The email is sending but the sender email displays as email that is configured as access point in .env to the smtp server on my production server. Locally with mailtrap everything is working fine.

Any ideas what is the problem? Maybe it is gmail configurations?

Comment: I don't think you can send emails via Google Main with any (in Gmail unconfigured) email address.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1332803/4201190 <- You can't. I tested!