# Change Cakephp Email Sender name

Tags: email, cakephp-3.0

I'm using Gmail smtp in Cakephp to send emails.
And I wanna make the sender as what i defined.
I've tried
`$email->from(['test@gmail.com' => '通知用メールサービス'])`
and
`$email->sender('app@example.com', '通知用メールサービス')`
but none of it worked.
So is it impossible to change or i did something wrong?
Thank you
sorry for my poor English.

Comment: Please check **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1332510/how-to-change-from-address-when-using-gmail-smtp-server**, this _should_ not be related to CakePHP.

Comment: Got it, new to this feature, thanks alot